# Fixed widths inside fluid layout

Tags: html, css

I need CSS definitions for the following layout:

```
<div id="middle-wrapper">
  <div id="column1-wrapper">
    This has to be 100% - 250px wide
  </div>
  <div id="column2-wrapper">
    This has to be 250px wide
  </div>
  <!-- no other markup in middle-wrapper except maybe a clearing div -->
</div>
```

- `middle-wrapper` needs to be 100% wide
- `column2-wrapper` needs to be 250px wide
- `column1-wrapper` should take all available space

In summary, `column1-wrapper` should be 100% - 250px wide and I need both of the columns to look like columns.

I've tried adding `float: left` to BOTH columns. However this means `column1-wrapper` looses its width. On pages that do not contain enough content in the left column, the right column aligns itself with the left column and ends up somewhere in the middle of the page:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| LEFT NO WIDTH COLUMN|| RIGHT 250 PX|
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried adding `float: left` to LEFT column and `float: right` to RIGHT column. That aligns the right column with the right edge but the left column does not stretch appropriately:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| LEFT NO WIDTH COLUMN|                          | RIGHT 250 PX|
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Try giving float:right to the right column and nothing at all to the left one. Don't float it, don't specify a size, just put the content you want inside it and that's it.

---

Oh sorry I forgot: you must put column2 **inside** column1

---

Yeah, this works:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
    div#column1-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }

    div#column1-wrapper {
    }

    div#column2-wrapper {
        float: right;
        width: 250px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="middle-wrapper">
    <div id="column1-wrapper">
        <div id="column2-wrapper">  <!-- Must be first -->
            This has to be 250px wide
        </div>
        This has to be 100% - 250px wide
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure if it's what you're after.

Comment: For that I'll first have to place the right div above left div in source order but that creates another problem... if left column is taller, some of its content will get placed below right column.

Comment: I removed an earlier, retarded comment I made. Sorry, don't have a solution for that.